# Unable to create a circular linked list in safe Rust; unsafe version crashes

Tags: rust, circular-list

I am writing a small strategic game, but I have a problem with implementing a circular linked list.

The game involves several people taking actions one by one and round by round until the game ends. I though that this could be done by using a circular linked list where each element is a player with a reference to the next player. The structure is like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    killed: bool,
    next: Option<Box<Player>>,
}
```

I also want a pointer to the current active player and be able to modify the status of it, but I think Rust does not allow me to have two mutable references to the same object because each player already has a mutable reference to the next player.

What I came up with is that I can use a simple mutable reference to the `Box` which is owned by its previous player and pointing to the current player. I wrote a simple main function where the problem occurs:

```
fn main() {
    let mut p3: Player = Player {
        name: "C".to_string(),
        killed: false,
        next: None,
    };
    let mut p2: Player = Player {
        name: "B".to_string(),
        killed: false,
        next: Some(unsafe { Box::from_raw(&mut p3) }),
    };
    let mut p1: Player = Player {
        name: "A".to_string(),
        killed: false,
        next: Some(unsafe { Box::from_raw(&mut p2) }),
    };
    p3.next = Some(unsafe { Box::from_raw(&mut p1) });
    println!("GAME STARTED!");
    let mut current_player = p3.next.as_mut().unwrap();
    let mut count = 0;
    while count < 10 {
        println!("Player to kill/save {}", current_player.name);
        (*current_player).killed = !(*current_player).killed;
        println!(
            "Player {} is killed: {}",
            (*current_player).name,
            (*current_player).killed
        );
        current_player = (*current_player).next.as_mut().unwrap();
        count = count + 1
    }
    println!("End!");
}
```

The error is also about the mutability but I have no idea how to fix it. I wonder if there is a better way to implement the idea in Rust rather than using a circular linked list and a pointer to the current player. Maybe should I switch to another structure?

The error message is quite long, here are the first few lines:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `current_player` (via `current_player.name`) as immutable because `current_player` is also borrowed as mutable (via `current_player.next`)
  --> src/main.rs:29:44
   |
29 |         println!("Player to kill/save {}", current_player.name);
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow of `current_player.name` -- which overlaps with `current_player.next` -- occurs here
...
36 |         current_player = (*current_player).next.as_mut().unwrap();
   |                          ---------------------- mutable borrow occurs here (via `current_player.next`)
...
40 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

If I change the `as_mut()` method to `as_ref()` which returns the immutable reference of the `Box`, and comment the line

```
// (*current_player).killed = !(*current_player).killed;
```

The program can build successfully but there will be an unknown runtime error when it finishes. Don't know why that happens either.

```
GAME STARTED!
Player to kill/save A
Player A is killed: false
Player to kill/save B
Player B is killed: false
......
Player to kill/save C
Player C is killed: false
Player to kill/save A
Player A is killed: false
End!
error: An unknown error occurred
```

Answer (score 12):

First, you should go read [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/README.html). Singly-linked lists *are not simple*, unlike how many programming languages treat them. Circular linked lists (or doubly-linked lists) are quite complicated when it comes to *ownership*, a core Rust concept.

If you have a circular linked list, **who owns each item?** This is important to know because the owner of a value is expected to drop the value.

Similarly, multiple mutable references are disallowed *for a reason*. If you want them, there are types like [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) that allow you to have mutability that doesn't directly correspond to the structure of the code.

The reason of the crash is right here: `unsafe`. You've told the compiler "this is cool, I know what I'm doing" and then you proceed to break all the guarantees that you are expected to uphold. If you want to use `unsafe`, you should read [*The Rustonomicon: The Dark Arts of Advanced and Unsafe Rust Programming*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/).

In this case, [`Box::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) specifically warns against what you are doing:

> After calling this function, the raw pointer is owned by the resulting `Box`. Specifically, the `Box` destructor will call the destructor of `T` and free the allocated memory. Since the way `Box` allocates and releases memory is unspecified, the **only valid pointer to pass to this function is the one taken from another `Box` via the `Box::into_raw` function**.

---

You don't need to create a linked list though; just use a `Vec`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    killed: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let mut players = vec![
        Player {
            name: "C".to_string(),
            killed: false,
        },
        Player {
            name: "B".to_string(),
            killed: false,
        },
        Player {
            name: "A".to_string(),
            killed: false,
        },
    ];

    println!("GAME STARTED!");

    let mut current_player_idx = 0;
    let player_count = players.len();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let current_player = &mut players[current_player_idx];

        println!("Player to kill/save {}", current_player.name);
        current_player.killed = !current_player.killed;
        println!(
            "Player {} is killed: {}",
            current_player.name, current_player.killed
        );

        current_player_idx += 1;
        current_player_idx %= player_count;
    }
    println!("End!");
}
```

Note that you don't need any explicit dereferencing.

Comment: I might be tempted to use [`Iterator::cycle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) on the `Vec` of players rather than manually incrementing and wrapping the index.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson that's a great idea! Unfortunately, you can't use `Iterator::cycle` with a mutable iterator: `std::slice::IterMut<...>: std::clone::Clone is not satisfied`. Otherwise we'd be able to get multiple mutable references concurrently. We could change the vector to contain `RefCell<Player>` and do a `borrow_mut` though.

Comment: @Shepmaster @Chris Another way to allow `cycle` is changing `killed` to `Cell<bool>`. It seems simpler than the `RefCell`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Rust `&mut` means not only mutable, but unique (same with `Box<T>` – `T` is assumed  to be uniquely owned by `Box`). Trying to work it around with `unsafe` will violate invariants and will lead to undefined behaviour. The error you get is because of that (my guess would be you're causing double free (recursively?)). If you want to stay with `unsafe` (not recommended), stick to using `*mut` pointers everywhere.

*Interior mutability* is what you want to do. You should familiarize yourself with the [cell](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/cell/index.html) module. [This blogpost about interior mutability](https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/06/08/interior-mutability) is also worth reading.

So, I'd redefine your struct like that:

```
use std::cell::{Cell,RefCell};
use std::rc::Weak;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Player {
    name: String,
    killed: Cell<bool>,
    next: RefCell<Option<Weak<Player>>>,
}
```

and keep all the players behind [`Rc`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) (reference counted pointer). If you plan for all your players to only live on the stack of the main function,

```
    next: Cell<Option<&Player>>,
```

should be enough.

Another option is to put the whole player in `Rc<RefCell<Player>>`, but it's considered good practice to put only mutable parts in cells.