# Multiple owners for Rust list elements (list owner and several referrers) - possible?

Tags: reference, linked-list, rust, ownership, borrowing

We have a struct with a `LinkedList`:

```
struct XPipeline {
    handlers: LinkedList<XHandler>,
}
```

`XPipeline` is the owner of all `XHandler` objects and can access and modify them.

We already have the list of handlers; now we need that each handler could refer to its neighbors in the list. Namely, each handler's method could refer to handler's neighbors, modify them and invoke their methods.

My first thoughts were like this: I provide each handler with `prev` and `next` fields that will refer to neighbors. By adding a new handler into the list, I initialize these fields with corresponding references. Now I can use these references within all handler's methods. (That would be easy-peasy in C++ with pointers).

The problem is: only one owner (i.e. with modification permission) is allowed. And that owner (of all handlers) is already a `XPipeline` object. How could I solve it? Maybe, by employing:

```
handlers: Rc<RefCell<LinkedList<XHandler>>>
```

But how exactly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to [show what research you performed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/155423) before asking this question. There's [another circular linked-list question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38353845/155423) on the frontpage of [tag:rust] questions when you asked this; how does this differ? What about the [50 or so other rust linked list questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+linked+list+is%3Aq); maybe some of those would be useful? Once we know what is confusing about all the existing answers, we can give you a useful answer for your unique problem.

Comment: I have searched through provided links and found no answer. All the questions were about other topics. For example, [another circular linked-list question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353845/unable-to-create-a-circular-linked-list-in-safe-rust-unsafe-version-crashes) is about implementation of a list with a kind of iterator. What I am asking is: I have a standard generic LinkedList + each element could reference its neighbors directly (so, it is a kind of double bi-directional list).

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an *intrusive data structure*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the strategies in Rust for multiple links in data structures is to use a `Vec<T>` as the backing storage and then index into it with `usize` "pointers".

Your case would look something like:

```
struct XPipeline {
    head: usize,
    storage: Vec<Node>,
}

struct Node {
    handler: XHandler,
    next: Option<usize>,
    prev: Option<usize>,
}
```

The bookkeeping is very similar to the pointers you would use in C++.

Also have a look at [this discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3shzmv/tree_ownership_woes/) for ways to deal with ownership in graph-like structures.

I would also just look for crates that implement double linked lists, skip lists, graphs or similar and take inspiration from there.

Comment: also check out the [linked list book](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/README.html)